# rspec stub to allow [hash_key] to be passed

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do you create a rspec method stub to allow a response from a method that takes in the hash key to return its value?

This is the line I want to test

```
sub_total = menu.menu_items[item] * quantity
```

and I'm using this line in rspec as my test stub on a double.

```
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items[item]).and_return(2.0)
```

My env is set up with ruby 2.2.0 and spec 3.1.7

However I keep on getting a

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `item'
```

#### Ruby code

```
def place_order(item, quantity, menu)
   sub_total = menu.menu_items[item] * quantity
   @customer_order << [item, quantity, sub_total]
 end
```

#### Rspec code

```
 let(:menu) { double :menu }

   it "should allow 1 order of beer to placed" do
     order = Order.new
     allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items[item]).and_return(2.0)
     order.place_order(:Beer, 1, 2.0)
     expect(order.customer_order).to eq [[:Beer, 1, 2.0]]
  end
```

#### Failures:

```
  1) Order should allow 1 order of beer to placed
     Failure/Error: allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items[item]).and_return(2.0)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `item' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Order:0x007fbb62917ee8 @__memoized=nil>
     # ./spec/order_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried a number of things but nothing has worked

```
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).and_return(2.0)
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).with(item).and_return(2.0)
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).with("item").and_return(2.0)
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).with([item]).and_return(2.0)
```

I've run my code in irb and I can see it works but I can't find a way to get my class double to recerive the hash key.

Comment: Seems like a brittle way to test things, but if you must, then have `menu.menu_iterms` return some `mock_menu_items` and stub `mock_menu_items` to receive `:[]` with `item` and return `2.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line `menu.menu_items[item]` is in reality composed by 3 method calls. `[]` is a call to the method [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) on the `Hash` returned by `menu_items`.

I assume `menu.menu_items` returns a `Hash` and not an `Array`, given in the spec `item` is a `Symbol`.

That means your stub requires a little bit more work.

```
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).and_return({ Beer: 2.0 })
```

Also note, the error

```
undefined local variable or method `item'
```

is because you were using `item` in the spec, but `item` is not defined outside your method.

Answer (score 11):

you can do this:

```
allow(menu.menu_items).to receive(:[]).and_return({Beer: 2.0})
```

You can also pass an specific item if you need:

```
allow(menu.menu_items).to receive(:[]).with(1).and_return({Beer: 2.0})
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going a little too deep with your stub, think of this instead

```
allow(menu).to receive(:menu_items).and_return({Beer: 2.0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SimoneCarletti's answer, I was able to easily stub an instance of `PublicActivity`. I add this answer only as a more brief (re)statement of the OP's problem and the simplicity of the solution.

Code I want to mimic with a stub:

```
self.entity = activity.parameters['entity_string']
```

And the salient parts of the test double:

```
activity = double('activity') # PublicActivity
allow(activity).to receive(:parameters).and_return({'entity_string' => "some entity name"})
```

Full code:

```
class ActivityRenderer

  attr_accessor :time
  attr_accessor :user
  attr_accessor :action
  attr_accessor :entity

  def initialize(activity)
    self.entity = activity.parameters['entity_string']
    self.time = activity.updated_at
    self.user = User.find(activity.owner_id)
    self.action = activity.key
  end
end

RSpec.describe ActivityRenderer do
  let(:user) { ...factory girl stuff... }
  let(:now) { Time.zone.now }

  before do
    Timecop.freeze
  end

  it 'provides an activity renderer' do
    activity = double('activity') # PublicActivity
    allow(activity).to receive(:parameters).and_return({'entity_string' => "some entity name"})
    allow(activity).to receive(:updated_at).and_return(now)
    allow(activity).to receive(:owner_id).and_return(user._id)
    allow(activity).to receive(:key).and_return('some activity?')

    ar = ActivityRenderer.new(activity)

    expect(ar.user).to eql(user)
    expect(ar.time).to eql(now)
    expect(ar.action).to eql('some activity?')
    expect(ar.entity).to eql("some entity name")
  end
end
```